# If $ln(y) = 5 - 0.1X$ what is the elasticity of Y with respect to X, when X=10?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, econometrics

So i got the following model $\log(y) = 5 - 0.1* X$ ...The question is 
"The elasticity of $Y$ with respect to $X$, when X=10 is..... "

i said -0.1 but apparently i'm wrong

Isn't the coefficient of $X$ the elasticity of $y$ when the model is a double log?

Is it rather -1?

It's a multiple choice and the choices are: $0.1, -0.1, 0.25, -0.25, 1, -1$

Comment: It would be the coefficient of $ln(x)$ in this situation.  The definition is $\frac{d \ln(y)}{d \ln(x)}$. Can you rewrite the function so that it contains $ln(x)$?

Comment: Maybe this will help - http://blog.modelworks.ch/?p=104

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elasticity is defined as the percentage change in $y$ after a percentage change in $x$. If you want to use calculus, then you can define the above statement as

$$El(y,x)=\frac{\partial y/y}{\partial x/x}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \frac{x}{y}$$

Now, we have the equation

$$ \log (Y)=5-0.1 X$$

Using the chain rule and recalling the derivative of the logarithm, after differentiating both sides w.r.t to $X$ we get

$$\frac{1}{Y}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X}=-0.1$$

agreed? What are we missing now? But of course the desired level of $X$, which we know that it is equal to $10$. Multiply both sides by $10$ then to get your answer.